# Angular 11 reactive form subscribe to valuechanges of input subscribing infinitely

Tags: rxjs, angular-reactive-forms, angular11

I am trying to subscribe value changes of reactive form input control. but this is getting subscribed continuously. I am not sure what is wrong with my code. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
this.sectionForm
            ?.get('sectionText')
            .valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(1000))
            .subscribe((_newVal) => { //getting subscribed continously
                if (this.attributes?.sectionName != _newVal) {
                    this.attributes.sectionName = _newVal;
                }
                this._validatorFunctionsService.validateAllForms();
            });
```

Comment: By `//getting subscribed continously`, do you mean the method is called multiple times?

Comment: no. it is getting subscribed multiple times

Comment: Please provide the entire code encompassing the above piece of code.
That is, if possible, the entire method calling the above piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good practice to use `distinctUntilChanged` with input controls.

```
this.sectionForm?.get('sectionText').valueChanges.pipe(
    debounceTime(1000),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
)
.subscribe((_newVal) => {
   if (this.attributes?.sectionName != _newVal) {
      this.attributes.sectionName = _newVal;
   }
   this._validatorFunctionsService.validateAllForms();
});
```